# When to use the best data store and when to stick to relational?

Tags: database, nosql, rdbms

I find myself very frequently taking the decision between storing a object in the data store more appropriate to its nature (Events, Documents, Graph, etc) or just sticking to the relational database and moving on with my life, and i bet some of you do too.

I'd like to know what criteria you use to take this decision, for example, when is using NoSQL with little data is "premature optmization" and when it is "good enginneering"...

So, When to use the best data store and when to stick to relational?

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of questions with the **nosql** tag that include the following:

1. They want to mix RDBMS and NoSQL systems.
2. They think NoSQL for large data out performs RDBMS always.
3. They believe data modeling is always easier with NoSQL.

From personal experience I would consider the cost of **discovery** when picking a new database.

It is far from easy to move data between relational stores and NoSQL. It's definitely not always intuitive how to model data when working with a document store. Also some of these databases are so new that their query optimization is no where near a relational system.

The things I mentioned above might not seem like a problem when you're doing a proof of concept or working with small amounts of data.

My recommendation would be to not let the hype get to you when picking a solution.

(I've worked with production implementations of Mongo, Couchbase, CouchDB and Redis.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Oracle and Couchbase(nosql document-oriented DB). I think that the use of the NoSql in most cases it is easier and less expensive. Every NoSql DB is a mechanism for solving a rather small range of tasks, and if under your task suited one of them, using NoSql solution will be more optimal than using monstrous large Oracle or MSSql Server. Ofter we use not more than ten per cent of the capabilities of these powerful databases, but not because we know them not at a high level, but because we just don't need all of leeway that they provide

Comment: Is it the same project? Did you start the project with Couch or started using after?

Comment: I worked on two projects on the basis of Couchbase. One originally used CB, in another project database part was migrated from Oracle to Couchbase quite well and easily. I should add that Couchbase interacts very well with ElasticSearch,  which makes this system very powerful.